# Match all value "IN" sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem with returning all match "IN" condition.

for example i have data like this:

```
table payment_history

id    order_id       payment_status_id
1      1              2
2      1              3
3      2              2
```

when i try

```
SELECT * from payment_histories where payment_status_id in (2, 3)
```

this is return both `order_id (1, 2)`, but this is not i want.

i want when `payment_status_id in (2, 3)` , just return `order_id  = 1`. because orde_id = 1 have all condition,

but order_id = 2 not have payment_status_id 3

sorry my english is not so good. but i hope you're understand what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation and `having`:

```
select payment_history
from payment_histories
where payment_status_id in (2, 3)
group by payment_history
having count(distinct payment_status_id) = 2;
```